# Alter the wrapper of radios buttons in a custom module

Tags: theming, forms

In a custom module, I have created a custom form. In this form, I need to alter the markup of the radio buttons wrapper and add a new attribute.
After reading many posts and testing, I can alter all the form elements (form-item, first fieldset...) except this wrapper.

This is the markup I am outputting.

```
<fieldset ...>
  <legend>Mylegend</legend>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
      <div id="edit-myfield"> <!-- < I need to alter the attributes of this div -->
        <div class="form-item js-form-item form-type-radio js-form-type-radio...">
    ...
        </div>
        <div class="form-item js-form-item form-type-radio js-form-type-radio...">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

I see that the related system template is radios.html.twig. I tried to copy and paste this template in the *templates* directory of my module without success. I tried to use `theme => 'my custom theme'` in the definition of my field. I tried to use a preprocess function in my module.

What is the simpler method to alter this wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in the form.

Add this to the radios element:

```
'#attributes' => [
  'attribute_name' = 'attribute_value'
],
```

Comment: Hello Jdrupal. The first solution add a new attribute on the first fieldset (and not on the edit-myfield div). And If I make a dpm in a form_alter I don't see a wrapper element. So I can't add a new attribute.

Comment: You should also be able to add it on the radios element, if you don't have a wrapper.